# Unable to Copy from E partition

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, xcopy

I am stuck in weird issue. I moved my images from my phone to a folder in Windows 8's Partition `E:/`. Now i am trying to move back to my Phone/Flash Drive/Other Partition/Other Machine(via Sharing drive) but it is failing.

I tried the `XCopy` command in command prompt. But it restarted my machine. Same thing happens when i try to copy my folder to flash drive and to other partition.

I tried to share it over network. But it hanged my machine(the one with this issue).

Lastly i tried to copy or move folder using safe mode. It turned screen to blank with only mouse cursor showing up.

While running in safe mode with networking. I tried to email those files as atchments. There i got error

`Unknown Hard Error` with `explorer.exe`

Comment: Waht was / is E;|  labeled -- moreover is it a system drive (system recovery for ex)  or a user created / sourced drive)

Comment: It is a system Drive/Local Drive

Comment: Are you saying as your copying your files back to your phone your system crashes?

Comment: I am trying to move back to phone or to other partition etc system crashes

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri: I'd advise you to run `chkdsk /f` (and if required `/r` too). Looks like some sort of file system corruption.

Comment: could also be a case of hardware failure.  Since Chkdsk can make things worse, the safest thing is to try to get a disk image.  (That generally involves using another hard drive of equal size, which may not be feasible based on your materials/budget.  However, many other approaches may risk losing that data, or even losing other data, so you have hereby been warned.)

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri What are the flags for that partition?(check it in disk management)